# docker not found in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm following the [basic example](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) to use jenkins pipeline with a docker image.

At the beginning of the build, I get a `docker: command not found` error:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on FleetCloud XXX in /tmp/jenkins-XXX/workspace/XXX-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . node:7-alpine
/tmp/jenkins-XXX/workspace/XXX-pipeline@tmp/durable-92bb0321/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull node:7-alpine
/tmp/jenkins-XXX/workspace/XXX-pipeline@tmp/durable-8317f88b/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
sh: line 1: 12623 Terminated              sleep 3
sh: line 1: 12636 Terminated              sleep 3
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is the Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {


    steps {
            sh 'node --version'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any idea on why docker can't be foubnd ?

Comment: did you install the docker  plugin? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin

Comment: @LinPy docker is supposed to be installed by default on Jenkins 2.5.0+ https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. Its not clear why it is not working. I do have the docker plug in installed.

Comment: Have this issue, docker not found, can figure it out. Did you manage to solve this?